# How to get data from callback function to another function in Nodejs + Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I know thats a silly question but i couldnt find an answer that fit with my request.
I`m trying to get a data from a webservice that return a Json and add it to an array of other data that i allready got from a diferent webservice request using one asynchronous function inside another one.

Here is the code:

### main.js

```
server.get('/app', function(req, res){

//This code get the categories data from a webservice
data.getdata.categories(userid, function(err, datos){
    datos.forEach(function(dato){

        //This function get data from a diferent webservice that return a Json
        data.getdata.subs(dato.name, function(response){
                if(response){
                    //response.total bring me an integer, this is the variable that i need to pass thru the res.render variables 
                    dataq = response.total; 
                }
                //for each category i need to store the number of subscription (the integer in response.total)
                datos.number = dataq;
            });         

    });

    res.render('app', {
        user : req.session.user,
        usertype: req.session.usertype,
        number : userid,
        listusers: ListUsers,
        listsubs: datos, // Here i get the data without the number value that i tryed to add in 2nd function
        permit: datos.length
    }); 
});
```

});

### in model.js

```
//This one request to a first webservice that return a Json
categories: function(user_id, callback){
        request('http://localhost:3030/getdata/*/subscriptions/user_id/'+user_id, function(error, res, body) {
            if (error) { 
                callback("error", null); 
            }else{
                result = JSON.parse(body);
                callback(null, result);
            }

        });
    },

    //This one request to another webservice that return a Json
    subs: function(cat, callback){
        request('http://104.131.7.130:8080/event/'+cat, function(error, res, body){
            if(error){
                return callback("error", null);
            }else{
                result2 = JSON.parse(body);
                return callback(result2);
            }
        });

    }
```

How a can pass the data from the second callback function to the first one?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you hoist a variable outside the scope of the inner function.  But you'd still have synchronization issues to deal with.

Remember that you'll be running async here, so the way you've written your function, the res.render would run potentially (and likely) before your `data.getdata.subs` calls.

If this weren't inside a `forEach` you'd obviously just put your res.render inside the second callback, but you need something a bit more complicated.

I would recommend the package [async](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/async).

Specifically, look at [async.each(arr, iterator, [callback])](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

Comment: _"the res.render would run potentially (and likely) before"_  It's guaranteed to run first.  JavaScript is single threaded - the entire outer function will run to completion before any async callbacks happen.